# Exception handler is not called when MaxUploadSizeExceededException is thrown

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using `CommonsMultipartResolver` for `multipart` files. I have a bean:

```
    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver() {
        final CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(maxUploadSize);

        return commonsMultipartResolver;
    }
```

And then a controller with method:

```
@RestController
public class Ctrl {
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity upload(MultipartFile multipartFile) throws MaxUploadSizeExceededException {
       ...
    }
}
```

And exception handler:

```
@RestControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
public class RestControllerExceptionHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler({
            MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class
    })
    public ResponseEntity handleBadRequest(final Exception exception) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Also I've configured `MultipartFilter`

```
public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
        insertFilters(servletContext, new MultipartFilter());
    }
}
```

And added `Tomcat` configuration to `conf/server.xml` file `maxSwallowSize="-1"`

But when I'm trying to upload file > max size I'm just getting screen with exception.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Maximum upload size of 1 bytes exceeded; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (172065) exceeds the configured maximum (1)
```

Am I missing something with the configuration ? I now that exception is thrown on tomcat level and maybe it just not possible to catch it inside Spring controller advice? I found few links with similar configuration and it says that it's possible.

Comment: I haven't try to implement `HandlerExceptionResolver` but probably it could help: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-maxuploadsizeexceeded

Comment: Yes I have tried it and it doesn't work for my dunno why

Comment: Then probably it happens because of ordering of the filters execution.